# Why is Header bigger than Title, when to use each?

Tags: uwp, user-experience, winui

Header styles are bigger than title styles in the [Window type ramp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/typography#type-ramp), which is opposite of common use in PDFs, Microsoft Word, and print. Why are these styles seemingly swapped, and in what scenarios did the designers intend us to use each?

Clarification: I am not asking how to "fix" it. As a developer, I need to know the original intent of the styles so I use them properly as-is.

[image: UWP Type Ramp Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It is by designed in UWP. But you could change these styles easily to adjust your thoughts.

For example, you could find the `HeaderTextBlockStyle` in **generic.xaml**(let your mouse poniter hover the `HeaderTextBlockStyle` in your xaml code and press **F12**), and copy the code of `HeaderTextBlockStyle` into your `Page.Resource` or `Application.Resources`. Then, change the `FontSize` property in a `Setter` statement or other target properties to fit your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. Do you know the intent of the existing styles? That's what the question is about.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to share your thoughts. As what I mentioned in the above answer, these default styles are by designed. If you have suggestions about the default styles, you could go to the Feedback Hub and submit a feedback.

Comment: You're answering a question that nobody asked. I didn't ask if it was by design.

Comment: Header and Title all of them called headline, you have no need to entangle with wich is bigger, And uwp support custom the style.  you 
 could use the suitable font szie  for your scenario.

Comment: @CoCaIceDew The [design docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/) show an _intense attention to purpose_, so I'm sure you are wrong to say the font sizes are arbitrary.

Comment: Ok, fine, if you do think this wrong, post this windows feed back hub app.